# Rust timerfd CLOCK_MONOTONIC equivalent

Tags: linux, rust, timer

In my Linux Rust program I would like to wait for the system monotonic clock to reach a specified value. (The Linux monotonic clock counts the elapsed time since system boot).

Here is the C implementation of the desired function, error checking omitted:

```c
void sleep_until_monotonic(int64_t ts)
{
  int fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);

  struct itimerspec its = { .it_value = { .tv_sec = ts }};
  timerfd_settime(fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &its, NULL);

  struct pollfd pfd = { .fd = fd, .events = POLLIN };
  poll(&pfd, 1, -1);
  close(fd);
}
```

Here is a sketch of the Rust API I'm imagining:

```
  some_lib::sleep_until_monotonic(1234).await?
```

Is something like this possible in Rust? A Linux-only solution is OK but of course if there is a cross-platform solution available that would be great.

Comment: Timerfd with [`ClockId::Monotonic`](https://docs.rs/timerfd/1.3.0/timerfd/enum.ClockId.html#variant.Monotonic)?

Comment: It's not obvious from the documentation that it can do "instant in time" type timers. The only way to set it seems to be via Duration: https://docs.rs/timerfd/latest/timerfd/enum.TimerState.html

However it also has an AbsTime flag, so maybe the "duration" is actually an instant in time, in that case?

Comment: Yes: "_The timer will expire when the value of the timer’s clock reaches the value specified in `new_value.it_value`._" And if you look at the [source code](https://docs.rs/timerfd/latest/src/timerfd/lib.rs.html#197-209) you'll see that it sets `TIMER_ABSTIME` just like your C code.